# Flow Creates Multiple Email Notices Each time File is Modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, service-account, power-automate

I am trying to create a Flow that generates a single email notice when three separate columns are modified in a SharePoint document library.  However, I cannot prevent multiple email notices from generating each time the file is modified.  There is an initial notice when the 'Employee Review Complete' column is set to 'Yes' (the employee changes this column).  The second notice should trigger when the Admin changes the 'Suzanne Approved' column to 'Yes.'  The last notice should generate when the 'Will Approved' column is set to 'Yes.'  The original email notice is generated with each subsequent notice each time the file is modified.

I am using the 'When a file is created or modified (properties only) trigger for the files in the document library.  I added a parallel branch to the Flow with 3-conditions.  In an attempt to stop the multiple email notices with each file modification, I added a Terminate control to the first condition with a 'Cancelled' status.  It works great for the first two conditions, the first and second email notices generate as expected with no duplication.  However, the flow skips the third condition and the last email notice fails.  I have tried various approaches to this flow and cannot stop the repeated email notices.  Thank you in advance for any assistance and or suggestions.

[image: First Condition]
[image: Second Condition]
[image: Third Condition]

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this solution yet but it makes the most sense even though it requires a bit more work to set up.  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-a-Flow-with-Service-account/m-p/367160#M41106

Seems like you are running into an issue where your Create/Update flow is doing something to the item the triggered the flow causing another trigger and basically going wild.  I did the same thing a few weeks ago and how numerous flows we had to kill.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this exact thing.  I had a Service Account created.  Then, I made a condition that checks who modified it last.  If the Service Account modified it last, then terminate the flow.  That fixed my issue that I was having with Flow repeating itself over and over.